# Docker agent volume mount in Jenkins pipeline not working as expected

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline, maven-3, docker-volume

Following snippet with volume mount creates the maven dependencies under `$JENKINS_HOME/workspace/<project-name>/?`   (Question Mark) instead of under `$HOME/.m2/`

Note that settings.xml mirror to our internal repository. And the instructions on how to mount has been directly taken from jenkins.io

Anyone has any clue why is this happening?

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'maven:3-alpine'
            args '-v /tmp/jenkins/.m2:/root/.m2:rw,z'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn clean install -s settings.xml'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is not as simple as using Docker in standalone. I have created /var/jenkins/.m2 directory on Jenkins slave where the build would be running. Ensured the new directory has 775 permission (although that may not be required) and also changed the owner to be the same as what is for "/var/opt/slave/workspace/pipeline_test" (got this path based on logs below)

```
$ docker login -u dcr-login -p ******** https://   nexus.corp.zenmonics.com:8449
Login Succeeded
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . nexus.corp.zenmonics.com:8449/maven:3-alpine
.
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
cucj1sb3 does not seem to be running inside a container
$ docker run -t -d -u 1002:1002 -v /tmp/jenkins/.m2:/root/.m2:rw,z -w 
/var/opt/slave/workspace/pipeline_test -v /var/opt/slave/workspace/pipeline_test:/var/opt/slave/workspace/pipeline_test:rw,z -v /var/opt/slave/workspace/pipeline_test@tmp:/var/opt/slave/workspace/pipeline_test@tmp:rw,z -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** nexus.corp.zenmonics.com:8449/maven:3-alpine cat
$ docker top c7282468dbb6952aadbe4bb495757e7047122b179c81516645ba23759b78c366 -eo pid,comm
```

This statement on official maven image at Docker Hub (https://hub.docker.com/_/maven) makes me feel the volume mount is updated

> To create a pre-packaged repository, create a pom.xml with the
>   dependencies you need and use this in your Dockerfile.
>   /usr/share/maven/ref/settings-docker.xml is a settings file that
>   changes the local repository to /usr/share/maven/ref/repository, but
>   you can use your own settings file as long as it uses
>   /usr/share/maven/ref/repository as local repo.

Comment: Possible that the `$HOME` is not set during the pipeline run resulting in `-v /.m2:/root/.m2` where `/` in the context of the `docker run` is set to the jenkins workspace directory. I'd use named volumes rather than bind mounting directories like that.

Comment: Hi masseyb, I have updated to add more details. We have builds running on Jenkins slave where Docker is running. We don't have Docker on Jenkins master, the role of master is just to clone the repository and remote it to appropriate slave based on its scheduling algorithm. If you notice the new logs posted above, the other paths that are volume mounted starting with /var/opt/slaves is on the slave machines.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation at : https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/ is misleading and waste of time when it comes to volume mounting.

When Docker container is created its created with user 1002 and group 1002. The user 1002 doesn't have access to /root/.m2 and only has access to the working directory injected into the container.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM maven:3-alpine

COPY --chown=1002:1002 repository/ /usr/share/maven/ref/repository/

RUN chmod -R 775 /usr/share/maven/ref/repository

COPY settings.xml /usr/share/maven/ref/
```

**Settings.xml**

```
<localRepository>/usr/share/maven/ref/repository</localRepository>
```

**Docker command**

```
docker build -t <server>:<port>/<image-name>:<image-tag> .
docker push <server>:<port>/<image-name>:<image-tag>
docker volume create maven-repo
```

**Jenkinsfile**

```
pipeline {
    agent('linux2') { 
        docker {
            label '<slave-label-here>'
            image '<image-name>:<image-tag>'
            registryUrl 'https://<server>:<port>'
            registryCredentialsId '<jenkins-credentials-for-docker-login>'
            args '-v maven-repo:/usr/share/maven/ref/repository/'
        }
    }

    parameters {
        booleanParam(name: 'SONAR', defaultValue: false, description: 'Select this option to run SONAR Analysis')
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn clean install -s /usr/share/maven/ref/settings.xml -f pom.xml'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As @masseyb mentions in the comments, Jenkins treat `$HOME` as current building context.

And there are two workarounds:

## a) use Jenkins plugin to set Env variable

You can use [Envinject Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject) to set environment variables in Jenkins.

## b) specify absolute path instead of `$HOME/.m2`

You can specify absolute path for `.m2`, e.g.:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'maven:3-alpine'
            args '-v /home/samir-shail/.m2:/root/.m2'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -B'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: please check that Jenkins has access to yours `$HOME/.m2/` directory.

Comment: Updated the original ticket and also see the comment added for masseyb above if it helps. This is not very obvious setup so the challenge. May be I will try volume mapping instead of bind mapping as masseyb suggested but I remember doing that before and didn't work.